# Eigenvector equation in a similarity score of regular equivalence for networks

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, network

In Newman's book *Networks*, it is given a *similarity measure for regular equivalence* $\sigma$ (in page 198, 2nd edition and page 217, 1st edition) as a matrix defined by

> $\sigma = \alpha A \sigma A$,

where $\alpha$ is a constant and $A$ is the adjacency matrix. Then it is stated:

> Although it may not be immediately apparent, this expression is a type of eigenvector equation, where the entire matrix $\sigma$ of similarities is the eigenvector. The parameter $\alpha$ is the eigenvalue (or more correctly, its inverse) [...].

**Question:** How do you see that $\sigma$ is an eigenvector with $1/\alpha$ the eigenvalue?